# scanner 4800H48U

Tags: scanner

I am new to Ubuntu and want to install a scanner 4800H48U
It's a Microtek flatbet USB 2.0 sold by Medion (MD90093) and MSN 5003 0446
lsusb give me  05da (microtek) and 3025 (product id) ;so my scanner is detected.
sane-find-scanner gives me USB detected but probably not supported by sane
scanimage -L gives No scanners where identified.

Quest: dus sane support this scanner ?
       Is there a driver missing and where can I find it ?

Some articles sugested that -rw permissions where not set (and scanner group)
I tried it with no results. 
How can we solve this problem,Ubuntu looks great.
Joris

Comment: the SANE project does know about it: [https://alioth.debian.org/tracker/?func=detail&group_id=30186&aid=314616&atid=410366](https://alioth.debian.org/tracker/?func=detail&group_id=30186&aid=314616&atid=410366) but there has been no maintainer assigned to developing the already partly finished code, it seems. last I tried, this driver doesn't work with current SANE versions. (dimmly I remember it worked badly when I bought the scanner.) so if you have this scanner then please learn about the SANE project and try to update the driver...

Answer (score 0):

`05da:3025` is not listed in the [SANE device list](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html%20SANE%20device%20list), so it seems the SANE project does not know about it. However, since similar scanners are unsupported, the chances of this one being supported are slim. You can still try to contact the SANE project, through their mailing list or by filing a bug report, to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

There are some devices SANE does not support and some that it says it supports but under "certain" conditions do not actually work. For example, I have a Canon Scan Lide 110 and it is in the list of supported scanners, but after trying all possible solutions in the web, none worked.

After much pain & hassle (2 afternoons and nights) I gave up in trying to make SANE work, and instead I used a 15-year-old mature & proven commercial application called VueScan and it worked instantly, like magic.

It works better and faster than the Canon-made Windows application my scanner came with.

This is the website for VueScan: https://www.hamrick.com/

Comment: I highly recommend it, I think there is nothing wrong with buying software so long as that software is high quality and worth the price (like Sublime Text for example), and I have strong reasons to believe VueScan is high quality software.